# Domain Driven Design Cache location

Tags: domain-driven-design

I have the following pseudo code

```
    public class ClientService
    {
        private readonly IClientsRepository clientsRepository;
        private readonly IClientsCache clientsCache;

        public ClientService(IClientsRepository clientsRepository,
                                IClientsCache clientsCache)
        {
            this.clientsRepository = clientsRepository;
            this.clientsCache = clientsCache;
            this.clientsRepository.OnClientCreated += OnNewClient;       
        }

        public IList<ClientDto> GetAllClients()
        {
            var result = clientsCache.GetClients();
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = clientsRepository.GetClients();
                for (int i = 0; i < result.Count; i++)
                {
                    clientsCache.AddClient(result[i]);
                }
            }

            return mapped clients...
        }

        public void AddClient(Clients newClient)
        {
            clientsRepository.Insert(newClient);
        }

        private void OnNewClient(Clients newClient )
        {
            clientsCache.AddClient(newClient);
        }
    }

    public interface IClientsRepository
    {
        event ClientCreated OnClientCreated;

        IList<Client> GetClients();

        void Insert(ClientsCache client);
    }

    public class ClientsRepository : IClientsRepository
    {
        public event ClientCreated OnClientCreated;

        public IList<Client> GetClients()
        {
            Get clients from database...
        }

        public void Insert(ClientsCache client)
        {
            //code to save to database...
            OnClientCreated?.Invoke(client);
        }
    }

    public interface IClientsCache
    {
        IList<Client> GetClients();

        UpdateClients(IList<Client> clients);

        AddClient(Client client);

        DeleteClient(Client client)
    }

    public class ClientsCache : IClientsCache
    {
        private readonly List<Clients> clientsCache;

        public ClientsCache()
        {
            clientsCache = new List<Clients>();
        }

        public IList<Client> GetClients()
        {
            return clientsCache;
        }

        public void UpdateClients(IList<Client> clients)
        {
            clientsCache = clients;
        }

        public void AddClient(Client client)
        {
            clients.add(client);
        }

        public void DeleteClient(Client client)
        {
            clients.remove(client);
        }
    }
```

As you can see there is a repository to get clients from database. Problem is I dont want to go to database every time I need all clients so I cache them.
I have a couple of questions about this:

1. Cache goes to infrastructure layer or not?
2. Do I need another repository to get clients from cache? Or is better to use a service that gets the clients from cache.
3. If I create a new client I need to add him to database and then add it also in cache. Do I need another service to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1. Cache**

Normally it should stay in the infrastructure layer. It's where you can "tune up" you're reads and make them faster according to the UI needs. So you can do this without messing up the domain. Hence, being the implementation of the repository not related to the domain but to the infrastructure, ...

**2. Repository**

... another repository is not a bad choice (here you're slipping in the CQRS area). So you can choose what fits better for reading (the cache) and writing (abstraction with JPA). 
But, then, do you really need a repository for the reads? When the reads are separated from the writes, and you're using two repositories, a service that access directly the cache would be also a solution. At the end, you use the repository only in the Domain, when you're out of it (the reads), you can use whatever you want for your needs. And then the service could be perfectly backed for the needs of the UI (or where you need the lists).

**3. Cache handling**

Id depends on how you're cache is handled. If is done simply by adding a cache on the request (the list is load via a ajax request, that could be cached), then the timeout of it would be enough and you've to do nothing. 
If, on the other way, you cache in another way (a list that get's updated every new Client), then you need a service that reacts to the ClientCreated event and updates the cache. 
The second choice requires also handling other events like ClientDeleted and so on.

CQRS links:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command%E2%80%93query_separation#Command_query_responsibility_segregation

https://www.slideshare.net/Codemotion/ddd-cqrs-latif?next_slideshow=1

http://cqrs.nu/

https://www.cuttingedge.it/blogs/steven/pivot/entry.php?id=92

https://cqrs.files.wordpress.com/2010/11/cqrs_documents.pdf

http://www.h-online.com/developer/features/CQRS-an-architecture-precept-based-on-segregation-of-commands-and-queries-1803276.html

Comment: I have edited the code and added an application layer service. It subscribes to OnClientCreated of the repository and when it is fired it updates the cache. Is that correct or there is a better way of achieving this?

Comment: If you want to dive in the CQRS (read also here http://galbenu.ro/2017/03/16/moving-to-domain-driven-design/), then use two repositories (but not on the same service). One for the store side, one for the read side (but here you'll not give back entities, just projections of them to use where you need). 
If, on the other side, you stick on the "pure" DDD, what says Constantin below here is right. Cache and Database are just a different implementation of the same repository; in your code according to your needs you wire one or the other.

Answer (score 4):

In order to respect the SOLID principles, in this case [Open closed principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open/closed_principle) and  [Liskov substitution principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liskov_substitution_principle), you could have only a single interface `IClientsRepository` that is implemented by both the `repository` and the `cache`. In this way you can always drop the `cache` and use only the `repository` without affecting the *correctness of the system*; of course, using the cache would boost the performance but the correctness should be the same.

So, your code could look something like that:

```
public interface IClientsRepository
{
    IList<Client> GetClients();

    public void UpdateClients(IList<Client> clients);

    public void AddClient(Client client);

    public void DeleteClient(Client client);
}

public class ClientsRepository : IClientsRepository
{
    public IList<Client> GetClients()
    {
        Get clients from database...
    }
}

public class ClientsCache : IClientsRepository
{
    private readonly List<Clients> clientsCache;

    private readonly IClientsRepository realRepository;

    public ClientsCache(IClientsRepository realRepository)
    {
         this.realRepository = realRepository;
    }

    public IList<Client> GetClients()
    {
        if(!clientsCache) {
            clientsCache = realRepository.GetClients();
        }

        return clientsCache;
    }

    public void UpdateClients(IList<Client> clients)
    {
        clientsCache = clients;
        realRepository.UpdateClients(clients);
    }

    public void AddClient(Client client)
    {
        clients.add(client);
        realRepository.AddClient(client);
    }

    public void DeleteClient(Client client)
    {
        clients.remove(client);
        realRepository.remove(client);
    }
}
```

Then, you can configure you preferred [DIC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) to use the cache or not, either way, the client code would not know or care.

About the layer, the `cache` should be located in the same layer as the `repository`; in my opinion they should be located in the `infrastructure layer`.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been automatically [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152532/discussion-on-answer-by-constantin-galbenu-domain-driven-design-cache-location).